# Create objects by passing different parameters

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a class hierarchy of interpolators like this:

```
class BaseInterpolator
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseInterpolator();

    virtual float GetInterpolation(const float input) const = 0;
};

class AccelerateInterpolator : public BaseInterpolator
{
public:
    explicit AccelerateInterpolator(const float factor = 1.0f);
    virtual float GetInterpolation(const float input) const override;
private:
    float m_factor;
};

class AnticipateOvershootInterpolator : public BaseInterpolator
{
public:
    explicit AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(const float tension = 2.0f, const float extraTension = 1.5f);
    virtual float GetInterpolation(const float input) const override;
private:
    float m_tension;
    float m_extraTension;
};
```

I would like to be able to construct these objects with different parameters. However, there is different number of parameters for each possible derived type from `BaseInterpolator`, i.e `AccelerateInterpolator` has 1, `AnticipateOvershootInterpolator` has 2. I have also class abstracting properties which client passes to my library which creates Interpolators based of those properties:

```
struct AnimationProperties
{
    enum class Curve
    {
        Accelerate,
        AnticipateOvershoot,
    };

    Curve curve;
    uint32_t duration{ 0 };
};
```

I would like to add possibility to user to pass different params via AnimationProperties, so I can create parametrized Interpolator using those params. Until now I've used unparametrized interpolators. I'm not sure how I should approach this. Should I use visitor somehow, or what is the correct approach?

Btw. User only sees `AnimationProperties`

Comment: Pass the structure as an argument to the constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Create objects by passing different parameter in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635742/create-objects-by-passing-different-parameter-in-c)

Comment: Can you get together with your classmate, [Ahmed Shahin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9559689/ahmed-shahin) and with your instructor.  You instructor needs to be informed of topics that were not communicated well.

Answer (score 2):

You need [Factory Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) - or even [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Keeping your naming scheme - it should look like following:

```
class BaseInterpolatorFactory
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseInterpolatorFactory() = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseInterpolator> CreateObject() = 0;
};
```

E.g. implementation for `AnticipateOvershootInterpolator`:

```
class AnticipateOvershootInterpolatorFactory : public BaseInterpolatorFactory
{
public:
    AnticipateOvershootInterpolatorFactory (float tension, float extraTension);
    std::unique_ptr<BaseInterpolator> CreateObject() override
    {
         return std::make_unique<>(m_tension, m_extraTension);
    }
private:
    float m_tension;
    float m_extraTension;
};
```

So - in client code, instead of passing some combined struct/union/discriminator of parameters - just pass `BaseInterpolatorFactory&`